# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "dejar/quedarse algo en el tintero"?

Tags: historia, locuciones

La expresión la conozco desde que tengo memoria, sin embargo apenas caigo en cuenta de que ni siquiera sabía el significado literal de la palabra tintero. Pensaba que se refería a algún recipiente donde se servía [tinto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Zo7qIdO)  (*Col. y Ec.* Infusión de café negro.); y que dejar algo en el tintero significaba que un poco de café quedaba en el fondo del recipiente luego de servirlo. Busqué en el DLE y veo el significado de tintero:

[**tintero**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Znrjcvd)

> 1. m. Recipiente en que se pone la tinta de escribir.

Ya con esto aclarado, se puede ver que existe una entrada allí mismo para la expresión que pregunto:

[**dejar, o dejarse, alguien algo en el tintero**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Znrjcvd)

> 1. locs. verbs. coloqs. Olvidarlo u omitirlo.

¿Por qué dejar algo en un recipiente que contiene tinta equivale a olvidarlo?

Otra cosa que me causa curiosidad es si el significado ha sido el mismo. Por ejemplo, en el CORDE se puede encontrar ejemplos algo antiguos de la expresión, pero me da la sensación de que no se usaba con el mismo sentido que hoy en día:

> ¡A lobos spantan los muchos ladridos!
>
> Mis perros se an visto en grandes quistiones
>
> contra Águilas fieras y brauos Leones. *
>
> Euandro. "Dexo en el tintero que fueron vençidos".
>
> <sub>(Francisco de Madrid, 1495, Égloga)</sub>

Yo eso lo interpreto, sin entender todas las palabras, como: "dejo constancia que fueron vencidos" ¿O tiene desde ese entonces el significado de omitir/olvidar?

Comment: No se por que signifique olvidarlo... yo siempre he encontrado que es para indicar que el omitirlo ha sido intencional. una frase muy digna de escritores

Comment: De cuando se escribía con tinta, mojando la pluma en el tintero. ¡Qué tiempos aquellos!

Comment: Yo apuesto mas por el significado de omitir, como que no se ha usado la tinta para escribir todo lo que se piensa, mas que en el sentido de olvidar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo que se deja en el tintero es tinta que no se usa, es decir, figurativamente, aquellas cosas que podrían haber sido escritas pero no lo fueron.

Si damos un paso figurativo más, podemos ampliar el ámbito de significado y decir que "lo que no fue escrito" incluye también "lo que no fue dicho, lo que no quedó establecido, lo que se dejó de hacer".

Estas cosas no hechas pueden haber quedado así deliberadamente (es decir, por decisión del autor, quizá obligado por las circunstancias), o inadvertidamente (es decir, sin que el autor se diera cuenta hasta más tarde). En ambos casos algo "se queda en el tintero", o sea, no es puesto por escrito (o no es dicho o hecho). Para mí la expresión tiene la connotación de que ese algo podría haber sido posible pero algo lo impidió, generalmente el tiempo o el espacio disponible.

Hay que añadir que, en efecto, hay ejemplos antiguos que parecen tener otro significado, o varios otros, pero quizá esto sea lo habitual cuando una expresión figurativa es relativamente nueva. Los ejemplos posteriores ya tienen todos claramente el significado actual.

Answer (score 2):

En mi caso ( locutor radial ) utilizo mucho esta expresión cuando estoy terminando la transmision y me quedan dos o tres notas: ¿"y que se va quedando en el tintero"? , digo al aire, pero lo refiero más a lo último que queda en la lista de notas ( la poca tinta sinonimo del resto de noticias ).